# Proper way to require external js and css libraries in ember js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, ember-cli

I have been playing around with ember 1.13 and I can see that in some online tutorials they require js and css via index.html while some uses ember-cli-build.js or brocfile.js for older versions. I find it requiring properly when I use ember-cli-build.js but then I am not sure what exactly the use of index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If you have a ember-cli-plugin it will add the files to the vendor files by itself normally. Like with [ember-cli-materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-materialize).

If you are installing a random bower package like [Ladda](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda), you would need to add the files you need manually to ember-cli-build.js:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  });

  app.import('bower_components/ladda/dist/ladda-themeless.min.css');
  app.import('bower_components/ladda/dist/spin.min.js');
  app.import('bower_components/ladda/dist/ladda.min.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

This will then be merged into your vendor.css and vendor.js which are linked to from index.html.

Also when you build the app the `bower_components` won't be available unless you've explicitly included something, so you cannot just link to them from index.html. It would also be a waste of network resources to include files separately. You shouldn't have to include anything in index.html unless it's an external resource.

**brocfile.js** is the old name for **ember-cli-build.js** since they've stopped using broccoli. Just use the newer one.